# R: Merging two files

Tags: r

I have two files. File1 and File2 of which I would like to merge.

File1

```
seqno   var1    var2    var3
7       1       65      2
7       2       64      2
7       3       37      1
7       3       26      1
8       1       50      3
8       3       29      2
8       6       5       1
8       6       4       1
```

File2

```
seqno   var4    var5    var6
7       1       65      9132
7       2       37      
7       3       37      
7       3       26      5162
8       1       50      
8       3       29      1314
8       5       26      
8       6       5       
8       6       4
```

Rows with the same seqno are on the same group. I would like to merge the files such that individuals in a group (by seqno) in File1 will have variables found in File2. That is, exclude individuals in the group that are not in File1 but are in File2.

Variables for comparison would be (var1,var2) and (var4,var5).

Output file should be like this.

```
seqno   var1    var2    var3    seqno   var4    var5    var6
7       1       65      2       7       1       65      9132
7       3       37      1       7       3       37      
7       3       26      1       7       3       26      5162
8       1       50      3       8       1       50      
8       3       29      2       8       3       29      1314
8       6       5       1       8       6       5       
8       6       4       1       8       6       4
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure that I fully understand what you want to do, because the `seqno` is not unique, so how should R know which rows to merge with which? Why is row 2 from file 1 merged with row 2 from file 2, and not with row 3 from file 2?

Comment: Im sorry for the confusion. The seqno is unique per group. The code would look at 3 variables. If (seqno & var1 & var2) are the same with (seqno & var4 & var5), then the rows will be merge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may be what you needed.

```
merge(file1, file2, by.x=c(seqno,var1, var2), by.y=by=c(seqno,var3, var4))
```